# Android: Put an image and a text view over another image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am trying to create a screen that has two background images and a text view with a language selection dropdown. The first background image fills up the entire screen and the second background image sites in the center. Then we have a language dropdown which is supposed to sit at the bottom. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I see that FrameLayout gives us this capability of nesting images one over another, however with my code, I am getting the language dropdown at the top instead of bottom. I am pretty new to Android and am fixing a few screens, any help is really appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_2" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.instructionview.WelcomeActivity">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/common_10dp"
            android:id="@+id/preferredData"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textColor="#2c5a99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_dashboard_line_outline">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/language_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/change_lang"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_20dp"
                android:text="English"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#343f45" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/change_lang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#183274"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="CHANGE" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.That will give you some start

2.Read the code carefully use some margin and padding to make this beautiful

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/chemistry">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/calculator" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preferredData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="fedsgsd vfsm "
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textColor="#2c5a99"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/language_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/change_lang"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="English"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="#343f45" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/change_lang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#183274"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="CHANGE" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using **[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)** instead of **FrameLayout** as it gives you more control and flexibility. If you don't know about ConstraintLayout, I would recommend learning it **ASAP**. You can through **[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N4bCdyGcUc&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuA80lNWNCLICR3qYzhw3iPI)** playlist for a quick and in-depth overview. Using ConstraintLayout you can achieve your desired outcome with a few lines of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/black"
   android:padding="24dp"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!--Here I have set height and width of the ImageView to 0dp
    So that I can maintain the same aspect ratio for all kind of screen sizes.
    -->
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```